# How to make it more efficient?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I'm working with some code like this (simplified):

```
var $form = $('form')
var els = {
  radio: $form.find('input[type=radio]'),
  check: $form.find('input[type=checkbox]')
}
```

The `form` in question may contain dynamically added inputs, but the `els` object is static when it's defined, if the form gets new inputs, `radio` and `check` won't change. I need to use `els` often throughout the code so I came up with this simple solution:

```
var getEls = function () {
  return {
    radio: $form.find('input[type=radio]'),
    check: $form.find('input[type=checkbox]')
  }
}

var foo = function () {
  var els = getEls()
  // do something with `els`
}
```

This works fine but I'm thinking this might not give the best performance since it has to query ALL elements again each time. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: how often are new inputs added? Could you just update your `els` variable when things change?

Comment: do you actually have peformance problems with it? if not, who cares...

Comment: **@MrOBrian** as often as they're needed. I thought about a setter to update but it doesn't make sense really because the selector will always be the same.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/ will tell you...

Comment: **@Karoly Horvath** Well, I haven't done any tests with other solutions but my code is getting big and I just wonder if this will be harder to mantain and if will affect performance in the long run.

Comment: There are live collections like [Form.Elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-dom-interfaces.html#htmlformcontrolscollection-0) and [`Form.getElementsByTagname('input')`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-A6C9094) but you would still need to iterate over the collections to get the checkboxes and radio buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't call `getEls()` in a loop or something performance should be fine. However, since you control the adding of elements to your form you have a few methods to streamline your code.

#### Use a property

Use a data property on your form to save the number of particular elements so you can compare it with your saved number of elements before doing a complete refresh.

```
function() {
    var checkBoxCount = parseInt($form.data("checkbox-count"), 10);
    $("form").append("<input type='checkbox'>");
    // now increment the count and re-save it
    $form.data("checkbox-count", checkBoxCount+1);
};
```

#### Update the collection

While you're adding the object to the dom, you could as well add it to the saved set.

```
function() {
    var $checkbox = $("<input type='checkbox'>");
    $("form").append($checkbox);
    els.check = els.check.add(checkbox);
};
```

Comment: +1 This is interesting, don't know if updating the collection is all that easy with my current code because I've a lot of selectors but it's a good idea to keep track of the length to not refresh when it's the same, but poses another problem because inputs can also be removed.

Comment: In that case you simply subtract from the count variable. Or to remove elements from a collection you can use `$.fn.not(/*element or selector*/)` which returns the new collection sans the passed element or selector.